# Why does Emacs org-mode ask for master file?

Tags: org-mode

When opening `.org` files, Emacs asks for a master file.

Why is that and how can I disable this feature?

I guess it is because of using latex-related packages like `ox-latex` and `ox-beamer`.

Is there a way to make the master file for `.org` files latex mode-specific or switch it off completely?

Thanks.

Comment: If you post (*here in your question*) the exact message you see (e.g., in the `*Messages*` buffer), then even someone who is unfamiliar with the particular issue you are experiencing can easily do a word-search of the source files to help troubleshoot your issue.  To enable broader debugging messages, you can use this:  `(setq debug-on-error t)`

Comment: @lawlist It is not an error. It just says Master file : dirpath/filenames .... Then I do C-j to cancel this but it slows down loading of the file. It was not asking for this before.

Comment: Emacs.SE is still a very small beta site. I've migrated it there now as an exception but we typically do not do this.

Comment: @slhck I thought of asking here only because it was not getting any answers on superuser. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `debug-on-message` to see a stacktrace when this message appears.

> — Variable: debug-on-message
>
> If you set debug-on-message to a regular expression, Emacs will enter the debugger if it displays a matching message in the echo area. For example, this can be useful when trying to find the cause of a particular message.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html

So, eval `(setq debug-on-message "Master file")` then open an org file.  That should point you to why it happens.  As for how to disable ... that might be worth a second question.

Comment: I have already asked it here and is the main purpose of asking the question as stated in the title.

Comment: There is no stacktrace when I add that to .emacs. Its not an error.

Comment: Hmm, maybe `debug-on-message` doesn't work on prompts.  Good luck debugging that one!

Comment: Could not find the function debug-on-message. Is it a built-of emacs or do it to install a specific package?

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem. For me it was the reftex that I added as a hook to my org-mode, and the error appeared as soon as I upgraded one of the repositories. You need to use the option:

```
    (setq TeX-master t).
```

If you don't know where to put it, have a look at the next link. http://draketo.de/english/emacs/writing-papers-in-org-mode-acpd#sec-2-1

Comment: Indeed the issue come from Auctex and not org-mode. I [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html) is the auctex doc related to this issue